# PCA matrix with sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

I did PCA on some data and I want to extract the PCA matrix. This is my code (excluding loading the data):

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=5)
pca_result = pca.fit_transform(recon.data.cpu().numpy())
M = pca.components_
```

I thought that M should be the PCA matrix. However when I print `pca_result` (first few rows) I get this:

```
[-21.08167   ,  -5.67821   ,   0.17554353,  -0.732398  ,0.04658243],
[-25.936056  ,  -6.535223  ,   0.6887493 ,  -0.8394666 ,0.06557591],
[-30.755266  ,  -6.0098953 ,   1.1643354 ,  -0.82322127,0.07585468]
```

But when I print `np.transpose(np.matmul(M,np.transpose(recon)))`, I get this:

```
[-27.78438   ,  -2.5913327 ,   0.87771094,  -1.0819707 ,0.1037216 ],
[-32.63887   ,  -3.4483302 ,   1.3909296 ,  -1.1890743 ,0.12274324],
[-37.45802   ,  -2.9229708 ,   1.8665184 ,  -1.1728177 ,0.13301012]
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the actual PCA matrix? Thank you!

Comment: Did you check these out:   
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html & 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html

Comment: Please update your post to clarify exactly what do you mean by "PCA matrix" - it is not a standard term. Do you mean the PC components? The transformed data?

Comment: @s.k yeah, the official documentation was the first thing I checked. That's how I wrote the code above in the first place. I am just not sure why the 2 methods are not consistent.

Comment: @desertnaut in a PCA you go from an n-dimensional space to a different (rotated) n-dimensional space. This change is done using an nxn matrix. I am not sure how that matrix is called. I have always called it PCA matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in a PCA you go from an n-dimensional space to a different (rotated) n-dimensional space. This change is done using an nxn matrix

This is indeed the matrix returned by `pca.components_`; when multiplied by the PCA-transformed data it gives the reconstruction of the original data X.

Here is a demonstration with the iris data:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

X = load_iris().data
mu = np.mean(X, axis=0) # mean value

pca = PCA()
X_pca = pca.fit_transform(X)
M = pca.components_
M
# result:
array([[ 0.36138659, -0.08452251,  0.85667061,  0.3582892 ],
       [ 0.65658877,  0.73016143, -0.17337266, -0.07548102],
       [-0.58202985,  0.59791083,  0.07623608,  0.54583143],
       [-0.31548719,  0.3197231 ,  0.47983899, -0.75365743]])
```

i.e. a 4x4 matrix indeed (the iris data have 4 features).

Let's reconstruct the original data using all PCs:

```
X_hat = np.matmul(X_pca, M)
X_hat = X_hat + mu # add back the mean
print(X_hat[0]) # reconstructed
print(X_[0])    # original
```

Result:

```
[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
```

i.e. perfect reconstruction.

Reconstructing with fewer PCs, let's say 2 (out of 4):

```
n_comp = 2
X_hat2 = np.matmul(X_pca[:,:n_comp], pca.components_[:n_comp,:])
X_hat2 = X_hat2 + mu
print(X_hat2[0])
```

Result:

```
[5.08303897 3.51741393 1.40321372 0.21353169]
```

i.e. a less accurate reconstruction, as we should expect due to the truncation in used PCs (2 instead of all 4).

(Code adapted from the great thread [How to reverse PCA and reconstruct original variables from several principal components?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229092/how-to-reverse-pca-and-reconstruct-original-variables-from-several-principal-com) at Cross Validated.)